# Does JEXL API work in Scala?

Tags: scala, jexl

Assuming that foo.method() can be call in a Jexl expression on java, is this possible to happen using the same api in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

Scala allows to use all Java libs, Jexl isn't an exception. So you can make a call of Jexl class methods in Scala as well.

As example:

```
val ja = new JexlArithmetic(false);
ja.add(null, null) // 0
```